# Why does pattern matching with instanceof fail to compile when using the boolean logical operator &?

Tags: java, if-statement, language-lawyer, instanceof, java-17

When using instanceof as a pattern match operator in an if-statement, the code fails to compile if we use the boolean logical operator &, but succeeds if using &&.

This DOES compile:

```
Number n = Integer.valueOf(9);
if (n instanceof Integer i) {
    i = 3;
}
```

This DOES NOT compile:

```
Number n = Integer.valueOf(9);
if (n instanceof Integer i & true) {
    i = 3;
}
// Hello.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
//             i = 3;
//             ^
//   symbol:   variable i
//   location: class Hello
// 1 error
```

This DOES compile:

```
Number n = Integer.valueOf(9);
if (n instanceof Integer i && true) {
    i = 3;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the second code snippet does not compile?

Comment: It must have something to do with the requirements for _bit-wise_ operations.  If you append the _instanceof_ check with an _&& true_, and then the _& true_, it works.

Comment: In this case & is the boolean operator though, not the bit-wise one (you can change Number and Integer to Object and String if you want). We already know using `&& true` works, so the fact that using `&& true & true` also works doesn't really reveal anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be because of [section 6.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3.1) of the JLS, which says that

> Only certain kinds of boolean expressions are involved in introducing pattern variables and determining where those variables are definitely matched. If an expression is not a conditional-and expression, conditional-or expression, logical complement expression, conditional expression, instanceof expression, switch expression, or parenthesized expression, then no scope rules apply.

Since the boolean logical operator `&` is not listed, the expression `n instanceof Integer i & true` does not introduce a pattern variable that can subsequently be seen in the body of the `if` statement, hence the compiler's error message "cannot find symbol".

Comment: What about `true && (n instanceof Integer i & true)`? Does that compile, considering that's a conditional and Boolean expression?

Comment: It seems like an oversight. It makes sense that the pattern variable wouldn’t be in scope on the right-hand side of the `&` expression, since that will be evaluated regardless of whether the left-hand side matches, but it seems like it should be in scope for the body of the `if`.

Comment: @TimMoore I don't think it is an oversight: the fact the cases are explicitly listed out suggests a deliberate choice. I'd suspect something about there not being any point in using non-short circuit operations since there is no side effect to the instanceof.

Comment: @TimMoore (but by the same token, I do wonder why it was necessary/expedient to exclude them)

Comment: @AndyTurner It does not compile with`true && (n instanceof Integer i & true)`, because the pattern variable never makes it out of the subexpression `(n instanceof Integer i & true)`.